# Vue.js modify other component's style

Tags: javascript, css, vue-component, vue.js

I am using Webpack with Vue.js to create a large-scale web app. The problem I encounter is the following:

I've am using vue-router and the following structure for the main app template:

```
<customNav></customNav>
<router-view></router-view>
```

The navigation is a single file component that has its own styles defined inside the component file. Let's say it has a black background by default. Now, on single occasions (when showing different views through the router), I want it to be transparent.

I thought I might just overwrite the CSS in the router view component, but this doesn't work because Webpack is bundling all the CSS of components I import, and I have to import all the components in the main.js to define them in the router. Therefore, overwriting the style in a component leads to it being the global default, even if the component is not even used.

How would I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take help of [dynamic styling](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.htm) of VueJS. You can assign a class, based on the value of a variable. So in your `customNav` You can have two classes: say `black-bg` and `transp-bg` and you can change this will help of a variable: `blackBackground`

```
<YourElem v-bind:class="{ 'black-bg': blackBackground, 'transp-bg'!blackBackground}"></YourElem>
```

I think you can change this variable in two ways:

- Have this as an instance data and change it based on current route.
- Have this in [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html) state and change in different components based on your requirement.

Comment: This looks like an approach to work with, although it for sure messes with the styling because now I'm styling using JavaScript - components are usually there to prevent this. I'll give it a try this evening and report back on how it worked. Thanks for your answer so far!